# Ember: Selecting the object form array using index in #each loop

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, each, ember-cli

Trying to use the index value in a loop in EmberJs

Consider the following scenario,

```
{{#each array1 as |element index|}}
<Component1 @prop={{element}} @prop2={{@array2[index]}} />
{{/each}}
```

I wish to send the object from the second array using the index value from first array. I cannot find any references to this. Any References i found use the first array alone and and didn't use the index in another variable.
Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get helper](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.16/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=get).

```
{{#each array1 as |element index|}}
   <Component1 @prop={{element}} @prop2={{get @array2 index}} />
{{/each}}
```